# How do I debug Intellij 2018.3.2 with maven when I am issueing a maven command via CLI

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, maven-surefire-plugin

I am issuing the command:

```
mvn -Dtest=RegressionSerialIT test -Dcucumber.options='--tags "@regression"'
```

I need to set a breakpoints in IntelliJ while the maven command is running and debug the test run in Intellij.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot issue this run from a Maven run target within IntelliJ? If you do so, then the IDE should be able to automatically configure the JVM to start with debugging, and attach.

Comment: Use `mvnDebug`, then attach to the port 8000.

Comment: This link (https://doc.nuxeo.com/corg/how-to-debug-a-test-run-with-maven/) should help.

Comment: @teppic how do you change the port in mvn?

Answer (score 1):

Steps I did to solve my question

1. Issue mvndebug -Dtest=RegressionSerialIT test -Dcucumber.options='--tags "@regression"' that would make maven hook up to port 8000 (there may be ways to change this default port association).
2. In IntelliJ Run-> Edit Configurations->Remote- Set a name to "Remote Test Maven" and set the port to 8000.
3. Hit the "insect/crawler" by selecting "Remote Test Maven" from the Run drop-down.

IntelliJ will stop at the first break-point you have set.

Comment: I just tried it again today and the debugger attaches to the maven command but is not stopping at the break-point. Looking further, but if you have any insights, would appreciate that.

Comment: There are pom changes where dev and test are using different versions of junit, that is probably causing this to not work anymore in my case. I havent found a solution to that. If anyone has ideas please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Use following command to debug surefire related test :
mvn clean test -Dmaven.surefire.debug

In IntelliJ, follow below steps 
Go to edit Configuration
Now on left panel you will see Remote option 
Select it and give it a name that you want.

That’s it.

**Now how to run**
Hit the above maven command in terminal 
Go to IntelliJ and run Remote Configuration in debug mode just simply clicking on debug button.

Now your program will run in debug mode.

Comment: @HudBud108 Did you set the port number in Remote Configuration setting?

Comment: Yes that was done. The issue is that the test run recognizes the maven run, but it does not stop in the break points.